# SOAP request with Security Headers (WSSE)

Tags: vb.net, web-services, soap, wsdl, wsse

I am linking into an external companies' WSDL file, which i need to use to send requests and recieve information back via SOAP requests.

They provided the WSDL file and i have added that as a 'service reference'. Normally this is enough, however whenever we send a request we need to attach a wsse header and security. We've managed to fumble our way through the adding of the header however there are some issues with it, which i'm not quite sure how to get around.

The Soap Request SHOULD look like :

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <wsse:Security
            xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
            xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-17A419BD1DC95B13F214417185709617">
                <wsse:Username>aUsername</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">##HashedPassword##</wsse:Password>
                <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">DUSgCUI8X3BJrVe8F+fGnQ==</wsse:Nonce>
                <wsu:Created>2015-09-08T13:22:50.961Z</wsu:Created>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
                <stuffhere />
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

My request currently looks like;

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss=-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <h:Security
        xmlns:h="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
        xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
        <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <h:UsernameToken u:Id="uuid-b9edaf83-70fb-4909-85eb-9773058c7001-1" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
                <h:Username>aUsername</h:Username>
                <h:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">##HashedPassword##</h:Password>
                <h:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">kRNsqdcQdv8T5y5rTv4O2WeidUM=</h:Nonce>
                <u:Created>2015-09-09T10:48:44.498Z</u:Created>
            </h:UsernameToken>
        </o:Security>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body >
        <stuffhere />

    </s:Body>   
</s:Envelope>
```

As you can see the security tags have messed up mainly. Also, the XMLNS tags seem to be all over the place, which I'm not quite sure if that will cause an issue or not.

Currently we are over-riding the header using the following classes (which i got from researching around);

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher
Imports System.ServiceModel.Channels
Imports System.ServiceModel
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.ServiceModel.Description
Imports System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ClientRuntime
Imports System
Imports System.IdentityModel.Selectors.SecurityTokenSerializer
Imports System.ServiceModel.Security
Imports System.IdentityModel.Tokens
Imports System.Security.Cryptography


Public Class CustomCredentials
    Inherits ClientCredentials
    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub New(cc As CustomCredentials)
        MyBase.New(cc)
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function CreateSecurityTokenManager() As System.IdentityModel.Selectors.SecurityTokenManager
        Return New CustomSecurityTokenManager(Me)
    End Function

    Protected Overrides Function CloneCore() As ClientCredentials
        Return New CustomCredentials(Me)
    End Function
End Class

Public Class CustomSecurityTokenManager
    Inherits ClientCredentialsSecurityTokenManager
    Public Sub New(cred As CustomCredentials)
        MyBase.New(cred)
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function CreateSecurityTokenSerializer(version As System.IdentityModel.Selectors.SecurityTokenVersion) As System.IdentityModel.Selectors.SecurityTokenSerializer
        Return New CustomTokenSerializer(System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityVersion.WSSecurity11)
    End Function
End Class

Public Class CustomTokenSerializer
    Inherits WSSecurityTokenSerializer
    Public Sub New(sv As SecurityVersion)
        MyBase.New(sv)
    End Sub

    'Protected Overrides Sub WriteKeyIdentifierClauseCore(writer As XmlWriter, keyIdentifierClause As SecurityKeyIdentifierClause)
    '    MyBase.WriteKeyIdentifierClauseCore(writer, keyIdentifierClause)

    '    writer.WriteRaw("TestClause")

    'End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub WriteTokenCore(writer As System.Xml.XmlWriter, token As System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityToken)
        Dim userToken As UserNameSecurityToken = TryCast(token, UserNameSecurityToken)

        Dim tokennamespace As String = "h"

        Dim created As DateTime = DateTime.Now
        Dim createdStr As String = created.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.fffZ")

        ' unique Nonce value - encode with SHA-1 for 'randomness'
        ' in theory the nonce could just be the GUID by itself
        Dim phrase As String = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
        Dim nonce = GetSHA1String(phrase)

        ' in this case password is plain text
        ' for digest mode password needs to be encoded as:
        ' PasswordAsDigest = Base64(SHA-1(Nonce + Created + Password))
        ' and profile needs to change to
        'string password = GetSHA1String(nonce + createdStr + userToken.Password);

        Dim password As String = GetSHA1String(nonce + createdStr + GetSHA1String(userToken.Password))


        writer.WriteRaw(String.Format((Convert.ToString((Convert.ToString((Convert.ToString("<{0}:UsernameToken u:Id=""" + token.Id + """ xmlns:u=""http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"">" + "<{0}:Username>" + userToken.UserName + "</{0}:Username>" + "<{0}:Password Type=""http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest"">") & password) + "</{0}:Password>" + "<{0}:Nonce EncodingType=""http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary"">") & nonce) + "</{0}:Nonce>" + "<u:Created>") & createdStr) + "</u:Created></{0}:UsernameToken>", tokennamespace))


    End Sub

    Protected Function GetSHA1String(phrase As String) As String
        Dim sha1Hasher As New SHA1CryptoServiceProvider()
        Dim hashedDataBytes As Byte() = sha1Hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(phrase))
        Return Convert.ToBase64String(hashedDataBytes)
    End Function


End Class
```

My web.config is currently configured as;

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="shippingAPISoapBinding">
      <!--<security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">-->
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"></transport>
      </security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="shippingAPISoapBinding1"/>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="https://www.anEndpoint.com/endpoint" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="shippingAPISoapBinding" contract="RMailAPI.shippingAPIPortType" name="shippingAPISoapBinding" behaviorConfiguration="ClientCertificateBehavior"  >
  </endpoint>   
 </client>    
</system.serviceModel>
```

As mentioned before we are sending requests using their wsdl which is done doing the following;

```
    'The securityheader we have to attach to be able to call createshipmentrequest1
    'The only things i can access on this are .Any or .AnyAttr which are XML attributes
    Dim securityHeader As New RMailAPI.SecurityHeaderType


    'We declare our requests here
    Dim cs As RMailAPI.createShipmentRequest
    cs = New RMailAPI.createShipmentRequest

    'assign values to cs here
    'These come through into the XML just fine

    Dim cs1 As New RMailAPI.createShipmentRequest1(securityHeader, cs)

    Try
        shipResponse = serviceClient.createShipment(cs1)
    Catch ex As CommunicationException
        Response.Write("msg:" & ex.Message & "<br />")
    End Try
```

I'm sorry if this is confusing, I've found this whole method very convoluted and I'm very sure I'm missing something very obvious here.

I'd be happy to provide any more information.

*Edit 1;

I tried adding my headers into the web.config, however there is an issue with that method as my password needs to be hashed before sending with a random string (the "nonce", which I also need to pass through). Not sure If i can change the web.config headers before sending.

*Edit 2;

Been looking to see if there's some way I can get the whole header, or if I can intercept it much in the same way I do with the "WriteTokenCore" function. To no avail!

Comment: Did you ever get any further in this? Struggling with the same Api!

Comment: I think you need to remove the previous headers and add them again with the new credentials, if you are having the same issue as me with the invalid for WS-Security message, I have been looking at http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Nov/24/WCF-WSSecurity-and-WSE-Nonce-Authentication which seems to help, just still not quite there!

Comment: Unfortunately because this project was taking so long I had to put it on the backburner. I started getting somewhere though, we were using a program called SOAPUI - which would verify our soap requests and let you know what was wrong with them compared to the example ones we were sent. I am planning on updating this when I pick it back up, but still in limbo at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I am getting somewhere as well by simply creating the xml from scratch. For the life of me I couldn't work out why two sets of headers where being sent using the current method

Comment: Hi @dave, We finally got past this, not sure if you're stuck on this or not. Basically with the API we were using our namespaces had to be the EXACT same, which is ridiculous as a practice, but we didn't have a say in the matter. We wrote out our own security header too, generating all the relevant information.If you're still stuck I'd be willing to send you some examples.

Comment: Hi @Feedel, thanks, I got past it in the end, same as yourself the namespaces had to be exact!

Comment: How did you manage to get this to work? I've been fighting with VS to get connections to the awful API for a few weeks and can't get it to work.